# Angular Async Form Validation with Injected Providers

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I have a custom async validator in a reactive form that needs to call out to a service to validate whether a name is unique.

Since validators are pure functions, there doesn't seem to be a good way to inject a provider such as HTTP to make these calls.

The code I currently have is returning a function that passes the service but this feels a tad hacky...

```
export function nameValidator(platformService: PlatformService): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: FormControl): { [key: string]: any } => {
        return userService.getUnique(control.value)
    };
}
```

my question is there a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Validators can be injectable [directive classes](https://angular.io/api/forms/Validator) when being used as directives in templates.

They are expected to be functions when they are specified directly in `FormControl` or `FormBuilder`

In order to make use of DI they should be `useFactory` or `useClass` providers and injected into a component:

```
@Injectable()
class NameValidator implements AsyncValidator {
  constructor(private userService: UserService) {}

  validate = (control: FormControl) => this.userService.getUnique(control.value);
}

...

new FormControl('', nameValidator.validate);
```

Notice that `validate` method is passed as a callback and should be either an arrow or be bound to class instance with `bind`.